# Unhandled rejection TypeError: domain.enter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: domain.enter is not a function
> at Child.emit (domain.js:536:10)
> at /mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:75:17
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Child.trigger (/mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:74:29)
> at Builder. (/mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:544:47)
> at Builder.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at Builder.emit (domain.js:475:12)
> at Runner.query (/mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:131:18)
> at /mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:40:23
> at /mnt/c/src/NodeiDocData/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:260:24
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

getting this error while creating the appointment,

- node version:14.21.3
- "bluebird": "^3.5.5",
- "bookshelf": "^1.2.0",
- "knex": "^0.20.11",
- "pg": "^8.3.0",

code is using the class components in react, we are updating the node 8 to 14 and the some packages

while creating the appointment, the details need to be inserted into the database(postgresql).,
instead of that getting the unhandled error: domain.enter() is not a function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: new this.Appointment().save(model, {method:'insert', transacting: t})
at this line i'm getting the error

Comment: Issue is resolved, just rename domain in both server and client side